# TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0" when running in linux

Tags: linux, tkinter, xlaunch

I have check all the other similar question from the stack overflow. But it does not help. The below is the procedure how I run the tkinter.

1. In window, I run **XLauch**,

a. Select "Multiple window",

b. Display number is set as 0

c. Choose "Start no client"

d. Select the "clipboard" and select "No Access Control"

e. Finish configuration.

XLaunch is running in my local Window OS.

I use putty to ssh the linux. I also enabled X11 forwarding by going to putty>> SSH>>X11>> select Enable X11 forwarding.

I ssh to the linux and set the display as localhost0.0. by using the following command `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`

I run the below code, but gives the error of **_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"**

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

May I know how can I solve the issue?

Comment: If you enable X11 forwarding in PuTTY, you don't need to set the DISPLAY environment variable after ssh into the Linux machine because it will be set implicitly.

Comment: First I run the script without setting the display environment. Then I got display environment error . So I set the display as localhost0.0. then I got the above error.

Comment: In the other Linux machine, I don't need to set the display and the script can run with no issue. I am not sure why my Linux provide display issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with same procedures.  The DISPLAY is automatically set to `localhost:10.0` implicitly after ssh into the Linux machine via PuTTY.

Comment: Yes acw I also tried in other 2 linux, don't get this issue. Only my Linux got error. I am not sure how can I solve the issue.

Comment: May I know is there any configuration that I can check in my Linux?